# Does sharepoint support webp image format?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, image, sharepoint-server

I have a designer's requirement for both SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint online to allow him to display images in webp format.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you

Capa

Comment: try it and then let us know. Put a webp in a document library and then reference it in  a script editor.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint 2013/Online does not recognize .webp as an image file. As a result, none of the out-of-thebox image-related SharePoint features will work. This includes:

- image webparts,
- image rendition
- Image sliders
- Image size (width/height) population in the Assets library,
- etc.

At the same time SharePoint will still serve .webp files as any other file that is not blocked by at the tenant level. Once Web server (SharePoint) serves this file - any modern browser will handle it automatically. For example, if you create a script editor webpart with this content:

```
<h1>2.webp</h1>
<img src="https://zergs.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/2.webp" width="400px" />
```

You will see that it's rendered properly:

[image]